# How do I get Eclipse to see that there are new files in a git repository and add them to the project

Tags: java, git, eclipse, import

I added three new Java files in my git repository (using Emacs) in a package (directory) that Eclipse already knows about.  I want Eclipse to recognize them as part of the project (as they are a new interface and classes that the other files in the directory now use) and without them Eclipse things those classes are unknown.

I tried import from file system, but it didn't seem to do anything, and when I did it from a "context menu" inside the tree view of the project it complained that the file system I was adding the files from was inside the project, which is true.  I put the files there so that when I do a normal "maven" build, that it finds them.  I just want Eclipse to understand that the git repository is the "source of truth" as to what the project contains and rebuild itself to include these new files in its data structure representing the project.

The problem might be that Eclipse isn't picking up the changes to the other files that now have added the new import statements.  I want to tell Eclipse.  Rebuild this project from "scratch" e.g. what I would expect "clean" followed by "build all" to do.

Answer (score 0):

if I add new code/files outside of eclipse to a git repo, I usually have to Right Click > Refresh the project in the project explorer in eclipse. Then the new files appear in the tree.

Comment: I tried that.  It didn't appear to do that this time.

Comment: do you have a .gitignore in place, that might interfere with those files being added to repo?

Comment: I now am trying to make a new project.  I've cloned the git repo into a new directory and trying to open the repo as a new Eclipse project.  That doesn't seem to want to work either.

Comment: the project does not open or the new files are still missing?

Comment: the new project won't open

Comment: if the project folder contains a .project file, open it with an text editor and check if the entries are correct, e.g. the name tag

Comment: Yes, I'm now trying to find the .project file.  I'm not sure whether it is in the git repo or in the eclipse directory in my home directory.  I don't normally keep files in my home directory, but I notice eclipse has things it keep there.

Comment: if it exists, it's directly in your project folder, together with .classpath, src folder, etc.

Comment: It exists, but none of the contents look relevant, e.g. it doesn't contain the list of files

Comment: I finally deleted from Eclipse my original project and the did a new import of the project.  Sadly reminds me of the xkcd comic about git, where the solution was to redownload and start over....